# ios - why does my UITableView not get populated with comments

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios5, ios6

I have a UITableView which is declared like this in my .h file:

```
@interface EnterInviteCodeController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *itemList;
@end
```

And then I declare it like this in my .m file

```
#import "EnterInviteCodeController.h"

@interface EnterInviteCodeController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *items_array;
@end
@implementation EnterInviteCodeController
@synthesize itemList; // UITableView
```

But when I try to populate the list, no items show up. Here is how I populate the list. I make a remote call to a server to get the items. And then when the server comes back with data, I try to do this:

```
                         items_array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
                         [self.itemList reloadData];

                         dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                             [self.itemList reloadData];
                         });
```

But the data does not show up. Would anyone know what I am missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bare minimum you need to implement:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and say you implement the UITableViewDataSource.

```
@interface EnterInviteCodeController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>
```

Also make sure you set the File Owner as the delegate for your table.

Comment: thank you! Just one newbie question, does that interface declaration go only in the .h file?

Comment: This line "Also make sure you set the File Owner as the delegate for your table." is a bit confusing. Could you please explain this a little bit more.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that should only go in the header. In interface builder, right click on your UITableView. You will see the outlets for it. Click and drag the "delegate" to point to the File Owner.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. You just mean that I should drag it to the .h file to connect the storyboard item to the .h ...I already did that part. What I didn't do was implement the interface. Thank you!